# Can not run Xcode 10.1 on High Sierra 10.13.6

Tags: macos, high-sierra, xcode

MacBook Air 11' mid-2011.

When opening Xcode from Terminal, I get this:

```
Kukoda-MacBook-Air:~ kukodajanos$ sudo open /Applications/Xcode.app 
Password:
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Applications/Xcode.app.
```

Do I need 10.0?

---

[image]

Following this thread: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/115847

---

Using `Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode` executable:

```
Last login: Fri Jan 10 10:20:11 on ttys001
Kukoda-MacBook-Air:~ kukodajanos$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode ; exit;
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/XcodeKit.framework/Versions/A/XcodeKit
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/Versions/A/IDEFoundation
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
logout
Saving session...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
Deleting expired sessions...1 completed.

[Folyamat befejeződött]
```

Comment: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 is the minimum version of macOS required to run Xcode 10.1. Make sure you have the said versions of macOS and Xcode installed on your Mac.

Comment: I am sure I have

Comment: @János it can be code sign issue, try the executable in show package contents under Macos folder.

Comment: Hi it says `IDEFoundation.framework not found` see more above